# Convert json response to string android

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

In my application, I get some response from the server in json, and then I have to get some certain string data from that response. As I got to know it will be better for me to use rxjava for my purposes. Firstly, I inserted some dependencies into my gradle, like this:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

But then as I understood I have to change my interface request from call to observable, however after it my interface doesn't work. So this question is still opened)) Anyway I have already read a lot of tutorials and all of them use observable, but I hope that maybe I will manage to solve my difficulties without it. 
And then the main question is - how I have to initialize my converter in my mainactivity class. I saw that sometimes we can get some fields which were in our answer class:

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public Post(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

But I don't need to get my password or username from the following class, I have to get my access token from my response and then insert it into my header programmatically. 
My initialization of Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://server/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Anyway thank you for your useful comments and answers, I hope that you will help me.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with RxJava, you can use retrofit for making a network call and getting the data that's pretty simple I guess.

Comment: You can use a GSONConverter with Retrofit to parse your JSON object, take a look at https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter (you already use the GSON lib with the @SerializedName annotation, you just need to add the converter to Retrofit)

Comment: I have updated my question, as you can see I had added such converter but I can't understand how I can fetch any string data from my responce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data from String like this :

```
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println("---------------- Responce : " + response);
                    try{
                        JSONArray obj=new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++) {
                            JSONObject jobj = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                            jobj.get("created_at").toString());
                            jobj.get("is_read").toString().equals("1"))
                            jobj.get("first_name").toString(),
                            jobj.get("last_name").toString(),
                            jobj.get("lastmsg").toString(),
                            jobj.get("profile_img").toString(),
                            jobj.get("online").toString(),
                            jobj.get("unread").toString()));
                        }catch (JSONException e){}
```

}

Comment: from json response to string , or from string?

Comment: you can cast the json variable by toString() method